# Spritefont for Greek

Tags: text, fonts, sprite, construct-2, spritefont

I am searching for a spritefont that can support Greek letters. I have downloaded the [Sprite Font Generator - v2 - Scirra Forums](https://www.scirra.com/forum/sprite-font-generator-v2_t86546), but all the fonts I tried won't understand Greek, as seen below:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try changing the character set on the upper left text-box (right above the font selection).

I could't find any charset suggestions online, so I'm posting the one that I used in my latest project:

```
ΑΆΒΓΔΕΈΖΗΉΘΙΊΪΚΛΜΝΞΟΌΠΡΣΤΥΎΫΦΧΨΩΏαάβγδεέζηήθιίϊΐκλμνξοόπρστυύϋΰφχψωώςƧИ«»’ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,;:?!-_~#"'&()[]|`\/@°+=*$£€<>%
```

Of course, you may change it according to your needs.